# Magento API 20x Slower On Local Dev Environment. Why?

Tags: api, soap, performance, wsdl, xmlrpc

I'm trying to test the speed of Magento API methods and finding it very difficult due to inconsistent results.  Right now my test consists of three API calls:  login, core_magento.info, and endSession.  When I query my development server, here are the (approx. average) response times I get for each method via XML-RPC, SOAP, and SOAP with WSDL cache enabled:

```
Method              XML-RPC     SOAP     SOAP w/WSDL cache
login               0.35s       0.30s      0.20s
magento_core.info   0.30s       0.25s      0.18s
endSession          0.25s       0.20s      0.16s
```

When I duplicated this test on my local environment I got wildly different results with each API call taking over 20 times longer.  It does make the WSDL cache look like a big win, though!

```
Method              XML-RPC     SOAP    SOAP w/WSDL cache
login                10.3s      10.3s     5.18s
magento_core.info    10.3s      10.3s     5.18s
endSession           10.3s      10.3s     5.16s
```

I found this very strange since my local machine is pretty powerful and I've given Magento (PHP & MySQL really) lots of resources.  Page load times are similar locally to the dev server.  Through additional testing with a default Magento install I found that removing `php_flag zlib.output_compression on` from my .htaccess file improved things in some cases, but not all:

```
Method              XML-RPC     SOAP    SOAP w/WSDL cache
login                10.3s      10.3s      5.18s
magento_core.info    10.3s       5.3s      0.18s
endSession           10.3s       5.3s      0.16s
```

At this point with the WSDL cache enabled, I'm getting very similar response times locally and on the dev server for the magento_core.info, and endSession calls.  Without the cache though, things are still an order of magnitude slower locally, and the login method is slow even with the cache.

So I'm trying to figure out what is different about my local environment to cause such different results?  If it was simply two times slower across the board I wouldn't think much of it, and just factor that into my testing. The size of the difference, and the inconsistency is disconcerting though.  I'm hoping someone experienced with the Magento API can weigh in on this.

Yes I certainly could just test on the server, but I really want to get my local environment to match server behavior.  Seems like a good idea, right?

Comment: I think every developer you talk to will say it is always slower on their local environments, however I think you need a apples to apple comparison more. Just because you have given your local a lot of resources doesn't mean it is in the same league as your dev server. I have done a lot of work with APIs myself and the first thing if I was you is to make sure you have the same server setup as your dev (as close as possible) and also the same setup for your mysql database. Are you able to put a bottleneck tracker on your database to rule that out? Is gzip enabled?

Comment: Yeah I expected it to be slower.  I didn't expect it to be 20x slower in certain cases, but just as fast in other cases....   gzip is enabled.  Not sure about a bottleneck tracker.  I'll look into that.